# Patterns inside Jqplot barchart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a requirement to show bars filled with certain symbol like whole bar filled with * so that when it is printed in black & white different series can be identified with the help of that symbol. Something sort of this (https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0oopz4qto04wal/BAR-GR.gif?dl=0[^]) i need with JqPlot. Can anyone please help in figure out how to do this with JqPlot?
If above is not possible, is adding legend text inside bars possible so that user can identify series with text instead of pattern?